# ImageButton in Layout always invisible

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm trying to make a layout for list items with an image to the left, two lines of text and the three little squares on the right, for a popup menu.

I have tried with `LinearLayout` and `RelativeLayout`, but the `ImageButton` element is always invisible. The preview shows as if the width was 0. I have no idea what to do, even setting `layout_width` and `minWidth` to some value did nothing.

Here is the XML for the element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd">

    <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="@string/content_description_collection_logo"
        android:id="@android:id/icon"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dip"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/text_layout"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@android:id/icon"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/text1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/text2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@android:id/text1"
            android:layout_alignStart="@android:id/text1"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/popup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/text_layout"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_overflow"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content_description_overflow_button"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@android:id/icon"
        android:layout_above="@+id/text_layout"
        android:minWidth="1dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I read that setting `minWidth` to `1dp` can help here, but it unfortunately did not. The Drawable exists and is 32x32 pixel png.

Comment: can i post the layout design picture u want

Comment: @Nithinlal Sure. But if you know why this doesn't work, that would help more.

Comment: so ur problem is image button is now not visible?

Comment: @Nithinlal My problem is mostly I don't understand why it is not visible. Learning Android layouts and such.

Comment: pls avoid the lines
  android:layout_toRightOf="@id/text_layout"
 android:layout_above="@+id/text_layout"
 and try

Comment: @Nithinlal Yes, that kinda did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong with that layout:

- android:orientation="horizontal" isn't relevant for a RelativeLayout
- android:gravity="right" is probably not what you want for the list entry, should probably left aligned?
- Add android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" to the ImageView to anchor it to the left side of the layout
- android:layout_above="@+id/text_layout" in the ImageButton doesn't make sense if it should be to the right of the two TextViews.

For your case it makes sense to use two nested LinearLayouts or one RelativeLayout. RelativeLayouts are sometimes good to replace nested LinearLayouts but I use them only of the number of ViewGroups can be reduced since it can be tricky to "configure" them correctly (alignment, filling the whole width...).

In your case I'd go for the LinearLayout approach because it's hard to position the ImageButton to the right of the two TextViews without adding an extra container view (as you did):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd">

    <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="@string/content_description_collection_logo"
        android:id="@android:id/icon"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dip"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="8dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/text2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@android:id/text1"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/popup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_overflow"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content_description_overflow_button"
        android:minWidth="1dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the attr android:layout_above to android:layout_below on yout ImageButton:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/popup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/text_layout"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_overflow"
    android:contentDescription="@string/content_description_overflow_button"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@android:id/icon"
    **android:layout_below="@+id/text_layout"**
    android:minWidth="1dp" />
```

I think thats a RelativeLayout problem, cause your text_layout is aligned at the top of the main view, and when you put layout_above your ImageButton will be placed above of the text_layout, in other words, will be placed off the screen

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="@string/content_description_collection_logo"
        android:id="@android:id/icon"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/text_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/text1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/text2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/popup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_overflow"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content_description_overflow_button"
        android:minWidth="1dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: -1 for code only answer. Do I really need to go through the complete xml and diff that by hand to see what you did differently?

Answer (score 0):

`RelativeLayout` Solution

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@android:id/icon"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dip"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/popup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_overflow"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content_description_overflow_button"        
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@android:id/icon" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/text_layout"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@android:id/icon"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/popup"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/text1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/text2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@android:id/text1"
            android:layout_alignStart="@android:id/text1"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```